# AWS Elastic Compute Cloud charging more than 24hrs a day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Amazons Elastic Beanstalk to host a Tomcat server. I am using the t1.micro free tier. However, for this month, my bill is for over the free 750 hours. 
[image]

As you can see, there is an additional 451 hours billed.

I have [read](https://www.quora.com/Why-ec2-instance-usage-free-tier-is-more-than-24-hours-per-day) that Amazon will bill an extra hour for restarting the server. There is no way I have restarted the server 451 times this month. I have deployed a new app probably around 10 times.

Does anyone know why Amazon are charging these 451 hours?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have two applications running:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Billing contains All Ec2 instance. Which includes all the running ec2 instance not only ec2 instance launched using elastic beanstalk.

Can you check have you launch any other instance other than elasticbeanstalk..?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have two applications running (see UPDATE above). Is the 451 hrs maybe for the other app? Does Free tier only allow one application?

Comment: Free tier only considering 750 hours of Ec2 instance not number of t2.micro instance. for example you can run 2 instance for 15 days or 15 instance for 2 days. hour only matters. @Richard

Comment: Thank you, thats was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

750 hours is not *per instance*, it is total. If you run 10 servers for 750 hours in a month, you get 9*750 hours of billed, and 1*750 paid for.